# setfacl default --x on directories and r-- on files for user

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

Having the following directory structure

```
[sr@server directory]$ tree
.
├── folder1
│   ├── fileA
│   └── fileB
└── folder2
    └── fileC

2 directories, 3 files
```

I want to set a default facl on folder1 and folder2 that, for the user `jim` has the following permissions

```
.
├── folder1      --x
│   ├── fileA    r--
│   └── fileB    r--
└── folder2      --x
    └── fileC    r--
```

I.E. all files have `r--` and all folders have `--x`

Any *files* created under folder1 or folder2 should be given the `r--` permission for user `jim`, any *folders* should be given the `--x` permission for user `jim`

I can set the permissions so folders created have `r-x` and files have `r--` but I can't figure out a way to set the default permissions so folders don't get the read permission.

While I can manually set the permissions for the currently existing files I want those permissions to apply as defaults to all newly created files and folders.

setfacl version `2.2.49` on RHEL 6.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you request is not supported by Linux's ACLs.

`setfacl -m u:jim:r-X` (capital `X`) gives Jim permission to read all files including directories, and to execute only directories and files that are executable by their owner.

Making directories non-readable has very limited usefulness. If you [tell us what you're trying to accomplish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), we might be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: I have a directory that another user needs to access specific files from, however I don't want to give them execute permissions on the directory to prevent them from listing the contents. Default ACLs seemed like the best way to go about achieving this

Comment: @sam I can't think of a simpler solution that adapting your directory creation script to call `setfacl`. You could do that with an incron rule if it absolutely needs to be automatic.

Comment: not perfect, but it'll work. Thanks