# Setting global browsable permissions for subdirectories (r-x) but making files inaccessible to everyone but the owner and group members

Tags: permissions, find, chmod

I typically have a directory where I want all users to be able to browse through but having files be unreadable and unexecutable.

I see some related questions that do not exactly match what I want:

- [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132194/how-to-set-umask-so-that-directories-to-be-r-x-and-files-to-be) is using `umask`. Doesn't apply since these files are already created.
- [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119637/setfacl-default-x-on-directories-and-r-on-files-for-user) is using ACLs. I want to use UNIX permisisons here though.

I usually use a `find` command but I'm aware it has some weakneses. I'll post it as a potential answer in a bit along with why I think there may be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use the following:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 440
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 555
```

However, that doesn't take into account executables. I was thinking of doing something like this for files:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod ug+r ug-w o-rwx
```

But it's still two commands and I'm not sure if this is the best way. Maybe someone has a better proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just don't set the same permissions on the directory and the files within it:

```
$ chmod g+rx directory/
$ chmod g= directory/*
```

Here, the group members can enter and browse the directory, yet they won't be able to read the files within it.

Edit: regarding your new title, I would suggest:

```
$ chmod a+rx directory/
$ chmod u=rwX,g=rX,o= *
```

Answer (score 0):

For directories and files already created:

> find /start_directory -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
>
> find /start_directory -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;

If your users should be able to create new files and/or subdirectories please give more details because a solution depends on exact requirements.